# Get readable info from NSErrorPointer

Tags: ios, string, swift, nserror

Is there a way to get readable information from the following `NSErrorPointer` in Swift?

```
var downloadErrorPointer = NSErrorPointer();
self.rssString = String(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: downloadErrorPointer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to directly use an instance of NSErrorPointer. Instead you create an optional NSError variable and pass it's address using the `&` operator, just as in Objective-C:

```
var error : NSError? = nil
self.rssString = String(..., error: &error);
```

But with Swift 2 there is new syntax for error handling so this cannot be used any more. The new syntax is the following:

```
do {
   self.rssString = try String(...)
   // Everything OK, the rssString is valid
} catch let error as NSError {
   // This only gets executed if there was an error
}
```

Comment: You can just use `catch`, right? `let error` is implied.

Comment: Yes, the `let error` is implicit, but then you don't get an NSError but a value conforming to the ErrorType protocol. If you require the information from NSError you'd still have to cast it